# Combine File.size? , File.file? and MD5

Tags: ruby

There are exist any possible ways to combine *File.size?* , *File.File?* and MD5 into solid one-line solution? For code:

```
puts b.times.flat_map {|level| Dir.glob("#{$basedir}*#{'/*' *level}/#{$pattern}").select {|f| File.file? f}}
```

This line allows to find and show only files by mask into directory and subdirectories, where:

1. b - how deep into subfolders file exist
2. $basedir - directory choosen for search
3. $pattern - file mask

Comment: Why do you aim for a one-liner? A one-liner that calls three different methods is hard to read, to understand and to maintain.

Comment: ok, without one-line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start with something like this:

```
def md5s(base_dir, level, pattern)
  files = Dir.glob(basedir, *Array.new('*', level), pattern)
             .select{ |file| File.file?(file) }
  files.map { |file| Digest::MD5.new(file).hexdigest }
end

puts b.times.flat_map { |level| md5s($basedir, level, $pattern) }
```

Comment: Seems like it has some problems with "no implicit conversion of String into Integer"

Comment: Could it find all routes? Like "./level1/level2/level3/level5/pattern-matching-file" and ""./level1/pattern-matching-file"

Comment: *no implicit conversion of String into Integer*: Is `level` an integer or a string? *Could it find all routes*: Yes, it should, doesn't it?

Comment: `level ` is integer.
it used in `'/*' *level` to define subdirs to check